# how to create Folder in google drive asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api

i can able insert a file but i didn't know how to create folder
i tried below code

```
private static string CreateFolder(DriveService service, string folderName)
{
var file = new File {Title = folderName, MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"};
var result = service.Files.Insert(file).Execute();
return result.Id;
}
```

i am getting null reference error 
where is my error